# Spring Boot: Customized Object mapper for Jackson Deserialization : List<Collection>

Tags: xml, list, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

How to read XML data which is of `List<Class>`? If we need to implement customized Object mapper than could you please share an example?

**Classes:**

```
public class data1{public int data2;}
public class Root {public List<data1> data;}
```

**Request from postman:**

```
<data1><data2>12345</data2></data1>
<data1><data2>67890</data2><data1>
```

Comment: Request:<data1>
    <data2>25992</data2>
</data1>
<data1>
    <data2>12345</data2>
</data1>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.